# File not landing in new directory created by askdirectory in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Firstly, thanks Carl_M! I will try to ask this question with more simple code. Using tkinker-

1. the user is asked to select the directory and new subfolder. That works.
2. Then browse for an exel file that will be modified as a df and sent to the new subfolder. That sort of works (thanks to Carl), but file doesn't go to the new subfolder. It goes to the selectPath. How can I add the path to the folder?

Used 'dirs = os.path.join(path.get(), folder.get())' to assign location, but it's not landing there.

```
def selectPath():   
    path_ = askdirectory()
    path.set(path_)
    
    
def create_subfolder():  
    print("folder_name: ", folder.get())
    print("path_name: ", path.get())
    dirs = os.path.join(path.get(), folder.get())

def openFile():
    filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir = r'L:\folder\My_file', filetypes=[("Excel Files", "*.xlsx")])
    os.startfile(filename)
    df = pd.read_excel(filename, sheet_name = 'Order Details')
    df.to_excel(((dirs) + 'Intelliscan.xlsx'),index=False)
```

Comment: None of the functions return values to be used in other functions.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. I added a return path_ and under the 'def SelectPath' and a return folder under the 'def create_subfolder'

Now it's landing in the select path directory!  how do i get it moved into the subfolder?

Comment: `dirs` is a local variable created inside `create_subfolder`. It has nothing to do with `dirs` used inside `openFile`. So you have to say `global dirs` inside `create_subfolder`. And I recommend to stop using `os.path` and use `pathlib.Path` instead

Comment: Note that `create_subfolder()` does not create the sub-folder at all.  Also missing directory separator between `dirs` and the filename in `(dirs) + 'Intelliscan.xlsx'` (assume `dirs` is defined).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
def openFile():
    filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir = r'L:\folder\My_file', filetypes=[("Excel Files", "*.xlsx")])
    os.startfile(filename)
    df = pd.read_excel(filename, sheet_name = 'Order Details')
    destination =  os.path.join(path.get(), folder.get(),'Intelliscan.xlsx')
    df.to_excel(destination,index=False)
```

Comment: @user19255018 I enjoy helping. I would appreciate it if you would accept the answer here, as well as in the question [File not landing in new directory created by askdirectory in tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72929205/file-not-landing-in-new-directory-created-by-askdirectory-in-tkinter), if the answer helped solve the issue.

Comment: Ok, I am not sure how to accept yet. Let me look around